# In Rails, making posts searchable by up to five tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

In Ruby on Rails, I am making something that involves posts that can be tagged, say up to 5 tags.  I want to be able to index the posts by the tags.

Is the way to model this something like:

```
Post attributes include:
  tag1
  tag2
  tag3
  tag4
  tag5
```

And then whenever you want to find a post with a tag, you do something like:

```
posts = Post.find_all_by_tag1(name)
posts2 = Post.find_all_by_tag2(name)
posts3 = Post.find_all_by_tag3(name)
posts4 = Post.find_all_by_tag4(name)
posts5 = Post.find_all_by_tag5(name)
posts.concat posts2
posts.concat posts3
posts.concat posts4
posts.concat posts5
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to make one table tags, attributes is name, product_id.
When your tags can use in another class. Please use polymorphic associations, attributes is name, tagable_id, tagable_type.

more detail about [concept polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) and example [practice polymorphic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not the best way.

use   [ActsAsTaggableOn](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem. Its built for you :)

Answer (score 0):

No, that will require 5 queries and may result in duplicate posts!

1) Have a `Tag` model, which has_many :posts. Every time you add a post, `find_or_create` a Tag for each tag on the post, then associate the post.
2) Find all the posts for a set of tags with something like:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
INNER JOIN tags on tags.post_id = posts.id
AND tags.tag IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

This will find all posts which can be joined to at least one of the tags in your IN clause. This solves the problem of multiple queries and post duplication, and doesn't require repetition on the taggable model. As pointed out, the ActsAsTaggableOn gem solves this for you, but you should try to understand what it's doing under the covers.